# Sound card is not being detected in Asus ha 200

Tags: pulseaudio, soundcard, video4linux

I installed Linux OS in my netbook. But sound card has not been detected. I think, codec are not developed/installed for it. It is HDMI technology. Sound card is working on Windows 10 with the help of Realtek driver.   Can I get sound by installing Realtek driver on Linux?

OS: Lubuntu 16.04

Hardware : ASUS-Vivobook-E200HA

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and add informations regarding the OS you're running - there are thousands of Linux-based OSes but we only support Ubuntu and official derivatives - and detailed hardware information. "Asus ha 200" doesn't say much.

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: It should just work. Are you sure a) there's a HDMI device connected and b) HDMI audio is selected as output. It's not automatic. Other than that there's something wrong with the installation or the hardware.

Comment: Please note HDMI is inbuilt. It is netbook.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the output of `sudo lshw -C multimedia` This will give us a chance. Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of the terminal commands `lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Audio`, `aplay -l`, and `pactl list short sinks`? Please also make sure that the relevant audio channels in `alsamixer` (terminal) or `gnome-alsamixer` (GUI) have their volume turned up and aren’t muted. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (≥100 lines) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.